# Searching Array For User-Defined Value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, interpolation, binary-search

So I have an integer array called OriginalArray that contains a bunch of integers. I want to be able to make it so that the user can input any value and if it's in the array, provide the location of that value and if it appears multiple times in the array, have it provide all the locations and otherwise have it provide an error message. 
I WANT to use the technique of binary search and/or linear search and/or interpolation search to be able to achieve this, recursive or iteratively I don't mind.

Sorry about the little information to go off trying to tackle a hard task for me and I'm not the most experienced :)

```
static object BinarySearchRecursive(int[] inputArray, int key, int min, int max)
                    {
                        if (min > max)
                        {
                            return "Nil";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int mid = (min + max) / 2;
                            if (key == inputArray[mid])
                            {
                                return ++mid;
                            }
                            else if (key < inputArray[mid])
                            {
                                return BinarySearchRecursive(inputArray, key, min, mid - 1);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return BinarySearchRecursive(inputArray, key, mid + 1, max);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: is the array always sorted? If not, then binary search would not make much sense.

Comment: So you definitely don't want to throw the integers into a dictionary ?